# Controls on TabPage change inexplicably

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, tabpage

On Visual Studio 2008, I have an instance of System.Windows.Forms.TabPage.

There are many controls on the TabPage.

Therefore, there is a vertical scroll bar on the TabPage.

Numerous times, all of the controls get uniformly shifted down, making lots of empty space at the top of the TabPage.  I must scroll down to view the first control, which should be at the top of the TabPage. This happens within Visual Studio and subsequently at runtime as well.

No event seems to trigger this shift.  It just happens.  Viewing the Location property for each control shows that they all shifted downwards by the same value.

I have had to manually fix this several times.  Then the problem comes back, usually days later.  I can work on the form.  It looks good.  Close it.  Come back later, and the controls have all shifted down by a fixed amount.

July 14, more information

Visual Studio 2008 is changing this:

this.groupBoxTrees.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);

To This:

this.groupBoxTrees.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 1030);

Why?  When?  For what reason?  I don't know.

Note the value 1030 is random too.  All I can say is that for some reason VS adds a constant value to each Location.Y property on every control on a TabPage.  All of the controls are locked.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the property Anchor of your controls setted to the bottom border of your tabpage?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't know.  I will find out.

Comment: No.  The Anchor property for the controls is set to:  Top, Left.

Comment: I'm still looking for help on this.  Numerous times now, the value of Location.Y has changed, inexplicably, changed on all of the controls that are on a TabPage.  This is getting expensive.  Each and every control on the TabPage is pushed down.  It's random.  I set the Locked property to True and still something has decided to change the Y value of every one of the controls.

Comment: Have you tried to build another form with a tab control, the same number of pages and just one control, closing the form and then reopen. If there is no problem then probably you have something broken. Also, add the tag for the correct language in use, you will get more people looking at your question.

Comment: Thanks!  I just added a C# tag and I'll do some more experimenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a colleague, I have found out what's going wrong.

If the form is saved when the scroll bar on the TabPage has been moved down, Visual Studio studio adds a number to Location.Y of every control on the TabPage.  That value is correlated to the distance the scroll bar has moved down.

The problem can be prevented by always moving the scroll bar to the top of the form before saving changes made by the form.

Why does this happen?  There is no way for me to find out.  It may be related to the fact that I'm using two monitors.  But then again, if that helps to cause the problem, then you would think that Location.X would be changed, rather than Location.Y.

Comment: Thanks for this, in 2021 VS2017 still happens, mine was horizontal, but same issue, relocated controls seemingly out of nowhere. And mine isnt tabconrol, mine is a Panel set to auto scroll in a tabcontrol.